# Trying to extrapolate function (some kind of $x^3$ shape)

Tags: functions

I would need to get a generic function $f(x)$, with variable $m < z < M$ from this characteristics:

1. $f(m) = 0$
2. $f(z) = 50$
3. $f(M) = 100$
4. $f'(z) = 0$
5. $f'$ is a increasing function with $[m,M]$ so $f''(x) >= 0$

I would like something like $x^3$ plot, so tried with $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + d$ and $f(x) = ax^3 + cx + d$, and to shift function to center it on $z (z = 0)$, so I tried

1. $f(m-z) = 0$
2. $f(0) = 50$
3. $f(M-z) = 100$
4. $f'(0) = 0$
5. $f'$ is a increasing function in $[m-z,M+z]$

In this case, with $m=10, M=90$, I can have something matching all points except point $5$, because it decreases between $0$ and $35,\cdots$.

I guess the problem is to use a $z$ offset which is not in the middle of $[m,M]$ range, so the $x^3$ is not applicable to the generic case.

[image: plot]

Please use this [link](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIwLjAwMTczNjExMTExMTExMTExMTQqeF4zLTAuMDkwMjc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3NzkqeF4yKzUwIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTMwIiwiNzAiLCItMTAiLCIxMjAiXX1d) for details

I still have the possibility to split the function into two intervals with two different functions, but for my curiosity I would like to know how a more trained mind would solve that issue!
Would you think of a function that could fit given $m, z,$ and $M$ are variable ?

Thanks,

Comment: Note that (4) and (5) together imply that $f''(z) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @BigM, I was looking for the guide to set correct formatting